# How to open different image in lightbox than it's thumbnail in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gallery, lightbox, portfolio

I am using WordPress and looking for a plugin or code through which I am able to open a different image in the lightbox. For example, I have images in the thumbnail when clicking on that thumbnail another image should be open in the lightbox. I want to open another image in the lightbox rather than thumbnail image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. You can try this simple step from the divi.

-> Firstly, install and activate the Divi Supreme plugin.

-> Go to Divi Builder and look for Supreme Image Module.

-> Under Link, Toggle “Open in Lightbox” and a new option “Use Other Lightbox Image” will show up then toggle “YES”.

-> Upload your desired image for the lightbox.

-> Save and Publish!

Comment: thanks, jigendra I really appreciate your help, but it's quite a simple lightbox plugin compared to others, is there any way that we can further zoom our lightbox image? For example please see the demo of this plugin when you click on the image, it will allow you to further click for more zoom  https://enviragallery.com/demo/lightbox-gallery-demo/

Comment: @SFAtta You can try with this.
https://divisupreme.com/blog/how-to-open-a-different-image-in-a-lightbox-in-divi/#:~:text=Steps%20to%20Open%20a%20Different%20Image%20in%20Lightbox&text=Go%20to%20Divi%20Builder%20and,Save%20and%20Publish!